# how to get distance by car ,by foot using google Map API for display only

Tags: google-maps-api-3

how to get distance by car ,by foot using google Map API

i am using this Api

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=mystartAdd&destination=mydestAdd&sensor=true

Comment: Documentation, maybe? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes  Note that you **must** show the route details, either in a text table or on a map. You cannot simply extract the distance figure.

Comment: Also, note that "Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 directions requests per day".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found that

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=startAdd&destinations=endAdd&mode=walking&language=en-EN&sensor=false

for help of this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes